# Android: How do you access viewHolder from outside bindView() method?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-viewholder

Below is a sample code of what I want to achieve.

```
    public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    ......

    public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

        viewHolder.refTextV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.refText);
        viewHolder.buttonIRV = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonIR); //For Ref Text
        .....

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewHolderItem viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();

        ......

        viewHolder.refTextV.setText(ref);

        ......
    }

    public void hideShowAll(Button but) {

       //I want  to be able to acess BUTTONS/TEXTVIWEs from this function.
       // Like viewHolder.refTextV.setText(ref) in binView

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
```

I'm trying to access elements of view like `Button`, `TextView` in `bindView` from another function within the adapter.

Also, please add a little bit of explanation, if you can, to your answers so that I can understand how it works and may learn something for future as well.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I finally used `notifyDataSetChanged();` in my `hideShowAll()` instead of accessing `ViewHolder` in there. I stored changes in an array and then called `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It refreshed my views and reflected the changes I wanted to make based on array.

Also, I had issue with get it work for me because some comments here mentioned to declare `ViewHolder` outside `newView` just after `Constructor`. This is not a good idea. You will get wrong `ViewHolder` instead of one that belongs to a particular row.

Comment: In almost all the cases, you don't need to access it outside.

What is the use case? Do you want to update some/all rows of recyclerView  on some action? If yes, then change your data model for the corresponding element and call adapter.notifyItemChanged(position).

Comment: the thing is **you should not access ViewHolder outside bindView**.

Comment: @PraveenSingh
 Thi function `showHideAll()` is being called from `MainActivity` on a Button I have an array that hold state(visibility) of the elements. I could use that to show/hide elements but the issue is I don't know how to refresh(if that is proper term) the view on screen. Rest of the Views will take effect on scroll because they will refer to the array for their state. 

This is my first app. 

will ` adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` refresh the state of current(on screen) view?  

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @PraveenSingh I am using `ListView`. My adapter doesn't suggest `notifyItemChanged()` as valid method. I have `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @pskink the one which is visible right now. Cursor Position. Rest of views will be updated when they are re-cycled. I want to update the one that is visible on screen at the time when user presses the Button. 
If I could find how to refresh current view without losing variables(their values) I may not need to access viewHolder then. 

Any idea?

I tried `notifyDataSetChanged();` from `MainActivity` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I meant row(which has two TextViews and Two Buttons)

Comment: Visible on screen at the point when user clicks the button. You can't see rows that are off screen. 

Do you have any idea how to refresh the view properly? If yes please let me know. 
If you can't help, please ignore.

Comment: I know this is used to refresh your view. I don't see it taking any position value.

So It will refresh I guess all list.

 `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

I already mentioned this method and said, I will just have to get this working and wouldn't need to access viewHolder. 

So you can change track if you like.

Comment: @AbuQatada I would advise to use RecyclerView if possible, it is much more efficient and flexible. Now talking about notifyDataSetChanged() not working for you, is because you are not associating your viewHolder with the dataSet in bindView. How it should ideally be is, you pass dataSet to your adapter, e.g a list of some data model. In bindView, you maintain state of a view based on the any field of the model at that index. This way notifyDataSetChanged() should work.

Comment: @PraveenSingh
Thank you, buddy. `notifyDatasetChanged()` worked fine. I didn't access `viewHolder` now. Just updated an array that holds state of my elements. 

Thank you.

Comment: @AbuQatada Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare '**ViewHolderItem viewHolder**' below to constructor and outside of all Override method and init into **bindView** method

Comment: Thank you, did that. 
Now I am facing another question. 

` viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(v.GONE);` In that function what should be this 'v' set to? This is supposed to be a `View` I am not sure which one. I tried 'View` in its place but it is not working as expected. I expect the `textView` to disappear that is one the screen now. It doesn't.

Any idea?

Comment: use this : viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize your  `ViewHolderItem` globally then you can access your views like `Button`, `TextView` etc in another `method` like this.

```
 public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    ......
// initialize ViewHolderItem here
ViewHolderItem viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
 @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        //remove this line here
       // ViewHolderItem viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

        viewHolder.refTextV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.refText);
        viewHolder.buttonIRV = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonIR); //For Ref Text
        .....

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return rowView;
    }

public void hideShowAll(Button but) {

       //call it like this and do what you want
        viewHolder.buttonIRV.setEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you for response. 
Did that. 

My problem now :

Now I am facing another question. 

` viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(v.GONE);` In that function what should be this 'v' set to? This is supposed to be a `View` I am not sure which one. I tried 'View` in its place but it is not working as expected. I expect the `textView` to disappear that is one the screen now. It doesn't.

Any idea?

Comment: `viewHolder.buttonIRV.setEnabled(View.GONE);` try like this

Comment: Tried it, akhi. Didn't work. 
I think it will not work. I am going to update an array to keep track of state of elements and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Trying to get that method working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
......

public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

    viewHolder.refTextV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.refText);
    viewHolder.buttonIRV = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonIR); //For Ref Text
    .....

    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewHolderItem viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();

    ......

    viewHolder.refTextV.setText(ref);

    ......
}

public void hideShowAll(Button but, ViewHolderItem viewHolder) {

   //I want  to be able to acess BUTTONS/TEXTVIWEs from this function.
    viewHolder.refTextV.setText("hello");

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Can't pass `ViewHolderItem ` to  `hideShowAll()`. The function is being called by another activity.

Thank you for the response